# how to specify a method to be passed as a parameter?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that takes an object, and a converter method that it needs to apply to the object:

```
def f x, conv
  conv x
end
```

how would I invoke it on a string and use `to_f` as the converter? this does not work:

```
f '123', &:to_f
```

EDIT: this is a contrived example, I know that this can be simplified or written differently.

EDIT2: thanks to these who suggests to use blocks, that works. I am trying to find out if this can be done with methods, like in functional languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yield` to execute a passed proc:

```
def f(x)
  yield x
end

f(x) { |y| y.to_f }
```

or if you want it the proc as a named parameter you can use `&`:

```
def f(x, &proc)
  proc.call x
end
```

You cannot just pass in a arbitrary function, since there are only instance methods in ruby, so you can not do:

```
to_f.to_proc
```

to get a function, if you want to do that you have to use `send`:

```
def g(x, sym)
  x.send sym
end

g(2, :to_f)
```

Remember, ruby is not a functional language, even though it has a lot of functional constructs, it is a very object oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must accept a block, which you have to call:

```
def f x, &conv
  conv.call x
end
```

or

```
def f x
  yield x
end
```

**EDIT:**
You can also pass methods as regular objects (you get one with `"".method(:to_i)`), but they behave just like procs and can't operate on `self` like they would when bound to an object.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if this can be done with methods, like in functional languages?

Comment: @akonsu Yes, this is what `map` is for.

Comment: @squiguy what is `map` for?

Comment: @akonsu It can transform a array based on a method.  I can add an answer, but it seems like you aren't talking about arrays.